# Syntax error in a single line if statement

Tags: python

I am new to python scripting on UNIX.
I am trying to create a directory but it leads to below error:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> path = "/u/home/user/exist"
>>> if not os.path.exists(path):os.mkdir(path)
... print "Directory does not exists. created one"



File "<stdin>", line 2
    print "Directory does not exists. created one";
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: @EdChum The OP needs to press enter before typing the next statement

Comment: @EdChum Type `if 1:pass` in the interactive shell, press return, and then, while still on the `...` prompt, type `a=1` and press return. Gives the same error.

Comment: @matsjoyce OK, understood the code looked a bit funny to me so I thought this was some funny terminal output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that you need to get out of the secondary prompt `...` before printing:

```
>>> if not os.path.exists(path):os.mkdir(path) # press an enter here!!!
...
>>> print "Directory does not exists. created one"
Directory does not exists. created one
```

This is the reason the Python Gods have always asked to refrain from using the single line `if` condition. Use

```
>>> if not os.path.exists(path):
...    os.mkdir(path) # Indent here!!!
...
>>> print "Directory does not exists. created one"
Directory does not exists. created one
```

This is the more **Readable** way.

*Note* : Reading from your code, the `print` must be a part of your `if` block. So please, please use:

```
>>> if not os.path.exists(path):
...    os.mkdir(path) # Indent here!!!
...    print "Directory does not exists. created one"
...
>>>
```